# Pulling two column values in single row if either 1 of 2 other columns in that row are true

Tags: ampscript

This is a bit of a complex scenario (at least to me) so here it is. I have a data extension (PriceDataExtension) that houses all the pricing information for the products that each user views and whether they purchased that product or not. The users are identified by an ID column (customerActivity) that I have already matched to the subscriber prior to this ampscript.

I am looking to scan the PriceDataExtension for all of that user's products that they have viewed then single out the only row that contains a "true" boolean statement in one of two colums: "BuyOnline" or "BuyOnPhone". Once I have that row I need to set @DEColumn1 equal to the "Brand" column in that row and @DEColumn2 equal to the "Price" column in that row. This is what I have that keeps throwing errors on me:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount
var @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = @customerActivity

set @rows =  LookupRows("PriceDataExtension","CustomerActivity",@lookupValue,"BuyOnline","true")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,1)
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"Brand")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"Price")

ELSEIF
set @rows = LookupRows("PriceDataExtension","CustomerActivity",@lookupValue,"BuyOnPhone","true")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,1)
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"Brand")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"Price")

ENDIF

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ELSEIF` part is wrong, you should use only `ELSE` and add another `ENDIF` at the end .

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount
var @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = @customerActivity


set @rows =  LookupRows("PriceDataExtension","CustomerActivity",@lookupValue,"BuyOnline","true")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
    set @row = row(@rows,1)
    set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"Brand")
    set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"Price")

ELSE
    set @rows = LookupRows("PriceDataExtension","CustomerActivity",@lookupValue,"BuyOnPhone","true")
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

    if @rowCount > 0 then

        var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
        set @row = row(@rows,1)
        set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"Brand")
        set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"Price")

    ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%
```